# Setting the interpolation algorithm / quality when transforming a CIImage

Tags: ios, ios8, core-image

I've noticed that shrinking an image with Core Image seems to produce some artifacts and the resulting image doesn't look as sharp as the camera preview. The code is pretty basic.

```
// `transform` is a CGAffineTransform object
transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, scale, scale);
CIImage *transformedImage = [image imageByApplyingTransform:transform];
```

Is there a way to control the interpolation quality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I researched a couple of techniques and found a couple of approaches that produce output images I'm pretty happy with. It was a lot more convenient to stay within Core Image, which can optimize a sequence of image manipulations, than to jump back and forth between Core Graphics.

I used the Lanczos Scale Transform filter to shrink the image smoothly:

```
// `image` is a CIImage
CIFilter *scaleFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CILanczosScaleTransform"];
scaleFilter setValue:image forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[scaleFilter setValue:@(scale) forKey:kCIInputScaleKey];
CIImage *scaledImage = scaleFilter.outputImage;
```

The other important thing was to make sure all of the geometry was calculated in pixels and not points. Working with pixels produces a significantly higher-quality image compared to working with points.

The Sharpen Luminance filter can help define the detail in the resized photo:

```
CIFilter *sharpenFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISharpenLuminance"];
[sharpenFilter setValue:scaledImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[sharpenFilter setValue:@(0.1) forKey:kCIInputSharpnessKey];
CIImage *sharpenedImage = sharpenFilter.outputImage;
```

Finally, the JPEG compression level really made a difference on some images. Around 0.9 it was producing quite clear images, compared to 0.75 which had some artifacts.

Comment: Hey Ide! We encountered a similar issue while working on our product. I'm sure your input could be highly valuable. Any chance you can take a quick look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57153640/metal-resize-video-buffer-before-passing-to-custom-kernel-filter/57163285?noredirect=1#comment100842018_57163285